# Join pandas datasets for weighted average calculation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two dataframes. The first describes relationships between Locations and Persons. The second describes relationships between Persons and Things.

```
>>> df1
  Location  Person    LP_weight     location_sum_of_weights
0 L1        P1        0.000019      27.641058
1 L1        P2        0.000010      27.641058
1 L2        P1        0.000023      33.144123
```

```
>>> df2
  Person  Thing   person_thing_score 
0 P1      T1      0.023
1 P1      T2      0.0031
2 P2      T1      0.0013
```

I want to generate relationships between Places and Things, using Persons to join the datasets. I'd like to calculate weighted averages so I believe the Dataframe I need looks like this:

```
>>> df3
  Location  Person    Thing   person_thing_score   LP_weight    location_sum_of_weights
0 L1        P1        T1      0.023                0.000019     27.641058
1 L1        P1        T2      0.0031               0.000019     27.641058
2 L1        P2        T1      0.0013               0.000010     27.641058
2 L2        P1        T1      0.023                0.000023     33.144123
2 L2        P1        T2      0.0031               0.000023     33.144123
```

Is there an efficient way of achieving this type of join with Pandas or numpy? Both tables have over a million rows therefore an iterative approach seems out of the question. I've tried to use multi-index groupby but am unable to get to a solution. I'm a beginner with numpy so I haven't been able to experiment with it thus far.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use pandas.merge for this and merge both dfs on Person

Comment: That worked! Thank you,  I think I was needlessly complicating the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
df1.join(df2, on='Person', how='left')
```

[pandas.DataFrame.join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)